# Alert Message when Web Part/Zone Removed from Page Layout

Tags: web-part

I removed web part zone from page layout and deployed it using FEATURE. I see the web parts and zone removed from all existing pages using that page layout. However, I see following warning first time I open the page:

"One or more Web Parts on this page references a zone that doesn't exist. It has been moved to the Closed Web Parts Gallery."

This happens for first user only after that the warning does not display.

Is there any way I can get rid of this alert message so that when I deploy the change in production, customers do not see this message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd have your feature activation code trawl the website for pages that use that page layout and remove the web parts from the zones.

Comment: otherwise sharepoint will remove it after/before showing alert message. Is it?

Comment: Yes. Though remember it won't remove it, it'll add it to the 'Closed' web parts folder in the 'Add Web Part' area in the ribbon.

Comment: Got it.. I would prefer a throw away console app for this one time operation though...

Comment: Yeah, same here. It's probably highly doable in PowerShell too, but I always reach for the Console app template in CKS xD